# Issues defining functions in Matlab

Tags: r, matlab, function, maximize

Having some trouble with my first night in Matlab. I was resting my laurels in R I guess...

I am trying to solve a problem for an equilibrium in infinite time of a Euler Equation.

Matlab seems much more apt for doing the optimization in this problem, but I am having some issues just getting started defining functions. Here is what I have:

```
%% ECON 20210 Honors Problem Set #2 Code
%% Writen By Jacob Miller
%% Date 4/17/2014

%% In this problem, you have to write 
%% a program to solve the following social planner problem:
%% Maximize The sum from t=1 to T over Ct,Nt, Kt+1 of the function
%% sum from t=1 to T of B^t-1*(Ct^(1-y)/1-y)-psi*log(n) 
%% subject to the constraint Ct=A(kt^a)*(nt^1-a)+(1-d)Kt-Kt+1

function [eul] = funkone(c,y,p,n)
eul = (power(c,minus(1,y))/minus(1,y)-p*log(n));
```

Which right now is returning the error:

```
EDU>> MillerEconPset2
Error using MillerEconPset2 (line 12)
Not enough input arguments.
```

It seems to think I'm trying to run the function, but I just want to define it. I have a similar script working in R:

```
myfunc<-function(c,y,n,p){
  (c^(1-y))/(1-y)-n*log(p)
}
```

But unfortunately R is not nearly as good for solving for global equilibria. Any idea how to fix the Matlab code?

Thanks a billion.

Best,

Jake

Comment: is MillerEconPset2 a script file? If so can we view it?

Answer (score 0):

A function is defined by creating a file containing the function and saving it with the appropriate file name matching the function name. Stand alone functions should be defined in separate files than your main script. You will then be able to access any functions you define in this way as long as they are in your MATLAB search path or current working direcetory.

An alternative that would work in this case would be to use an anonymous function. That is:

```
funkone = @(c,y,p,n) (power(c,minus(1,y))/minus(1,y)-p*log(n));
```

which could be called as

```
ouput_val = funkone(c,y,p,n)
```